# 'D:\flutter' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: flutter, gradle, visual-studio-code, android-emulator, assemble

Launching lib\main.dart on SM A908N in debug mode...
lib\main.dart:1
'D:\flutter' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)

Comment: I think you need to recheck the [installation processes](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/windows)

Answer (score 0):

As per flutter installation it's installed in `C:\src\flutter\bin`
if you find flutter in this location  `C:\src\flutter\bin`  then, go to Environmental variable and set the Path to `C:\src\flutter\bin` after this **close all you're terminal** restart your pc to make sure then **run flutter doctor** in terminal this might help you get going I hope.

Answer (score -1):

You set worng flutter path , ur path should be "D:\flutter\bin"